# How to securely connect to localhost websocket server

Tags: c, websocket, https, certificate

I'm developing a WebSocket backend server in C using libssl and want to test how it works. I have a remote server and domain with a certificate already set up (HTTPS works on a website).

The server binary is built locally and I want to test it by opening the abstract page in the browser that contains js for it. The point is that I've created a self-signed certificate but I still can not connect, OpenSSL says it is a bad certificate. I'm using the latest Firefox dev. The server itself is not reaching WebSocket establish a point and failing on SSL accept function.

Comment: So tell your client to accept the certificate. What kind of magic do you expect to happen?

Answer (score 0):

If you have admin privileges on the POS terminals, how about adding a line to the HOSTS file like:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost.mycompany.com
```

Now you can use a real certificate for `localhost.mycompany.com` in the server application.

Comment: So what you are trying to say is to make a DNS record with 127.0.0.1 as a target and then I will be browsing from domain but on localhost? Sounds like a solid plan... Am I understanding you correct here?

Comment: And actually I don't have any POS terminals, it is a web app (or only admin page as a web app), server that submits info to database and website that shows it. I have control over dns records but I don't have private key on hands and don't really want to move one to my pc for testing